# Interrupt method execution after arbitrary time in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, multithreading

I have some method doA() that occasionally hangs for a while. Are there any common modules in Python that can control time of doA() execution and interrupt it?
Of course, it may be implemented via threads, so simple wrapper around threading module may be good solution.

In other words i'd like to have code like:

```
import CoolAsyncControl
CoolAsyncControl.call(self.doA, timeout = 10)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [threading.Timer](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html?highlight=timer#threading.Timer) to call [thread.interrupt_main](http://docs.python.org/library/thread.html#thread.interrupt_main), as long as you're running `doA` in the main thread.  Note that the syntax you desire is impossible because Python (like most languages, excepting e.g. Haskell) is "eager" -- arguments are entirely computed before a call is performed, so the `self.doA()` would run to completion **before** the `call` method has any chance to do anything about it!  You'll have to use some syntax such as

```
CoolIt.call(self.doA, args=(), timeout=100)
```

so that `call` can set the timer up **before** performing the call to `doA` with the given arguments.

Comment: Thanks! It is just what i'm looking for. Of course, i mean self.doA in my code